# JAVA Dans DBF Library, get data from DBF file, byte[] to int

Tags: java, string, integer, byte, dbf

I'm new to Java (about 3 moths ago) and now I'm trying to get data from DBF file using java program. I already got Dans DBF library to connect my program with DBF file. I'm using this code to open the file:

```
Table table = new Table(new File(Filename)); // get the file

try {
    table.open(IfNonExistent.ERROR); // open the file
} catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("Error : " + e);
}

List<Field> fields = table.getFields(); // get the column
Iterator<Record> recordIterator = table.recordIterator(); // get the rows
```

if I'm going to get the data, I'm using this code

```
byte[] rawValue = record.getRawValue(fields.get(1)); // to get data from row column 1
```

the problem is, the rawValue is byte[]. I can convert the data to String, but I cannot convert the data into integer. I have already try this:

```
Integer.parseInt(new String(rawValue))
```

But it cannot be done. I suspect the rawValue store some space not only number character. Can anyone help me with this problem?

edit:
to make it more clear, I already try to do this:

```
System.out.println(new String(rawValue));
```

The output will be something like [     300] (ignore the [])
I notice there are some blank space before 300.

Comment: What does it look like in String form?

Comment: System.out.println(new String (rawValue)); will print something like 
[   300] (ignore the []) I notice there are some spacing field before 300.

Comment: How about `(new String(rawValue)).trim()`? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()

Comment: thanks for the tips, your tips solve my problem thank a lot!

Comment: thanks for the tips, your tips solve my problem thank a lot!

Answer (score 0):

How to convert the raw bytes of a numeric field depends on its actual type, which is stored as a single character in the field definition. There's a [good overview on clicketyclick](http://www.clicketyclick.dk/databases/xbase/format/data_types.html).

Here's how FoxPro writes numbers:

**'N'**: the number is stored as a string that may contain a leading sign and a decimal separator, padded to the field size with blanks. The integer portion may push defined decimal places out at the right (i.e. writing 10 to a field defined as n(3,1) results in '10.'); on overflow the field will be filled with asterisks (like when writing 10 to a field defined as n(1)).

**'I'**: raw 32-bit integer (Little Endian); the value 0x80000000 (-2^31) is forbidden and represents overflow.

**'B'**: [raw 64-bit IEEE double](http://www.clicketyclick.dk/databases/xbase/format/data_types.html) (a.k.a. 'binary64').

**'Y'**: raw 64-bit integer (Little Endian) scaled by 10000

Note: DBF files are often written by homegrown code that doesn't stick to any of the de-facto standards set by programs like dBASE or Fox, so caveat emptor. Fox and dBASE won't write a numeric field with raw contents like [ 300] so you may have a string field on your hands or something written by a b0rked tool.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the responses. Especially for PM 77-1's comment

```
Integer.parseInt(new String(rawValue).trim())
```

solve the problem.